# Event listeners in the init of a JavaScript component

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, components

It is actually the first time I am trying not to do spaguetti code, so it means I am new in this component world.

I have being selected to develop our new top nav bar. And even if it is something really simple... I would like to do a JS component for it.

More or less there is an sketch here: https://codepen.io/tureey/pen/qXQJYv

**My problem:**
I have something like this now.

```
function Menu ( view, device, resolutionX, resolutionY) {
        this.collapsed  = false;
        this.view           = view;
        this.device         = device;
        this.search         = '';
        this.resolution = {
            x: resolutionX,
            y: resolutionY
        };
    }

// So, this would be nice to have it in a resize eventlistenner once we init our menu
Menu.Prototype.changeVersionbyResolution = function() {
    // This should be casted if we resize the windows less than 992px
    // It adds/removes classes to the whole menu to display the things totally different
}

// So, this would be nice to have it in a scroll eventlistenner once we init our menu
Menu.Prototype.collapse = function() {
    // This should be casted if we scroll down
    // It adds/removes classes to the whole menu to display the things totally different
}

var menu = new Menu('ng_live_events', 'xiaomi mi5s', window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

**I would like to:**

The own menu should be able to change himself (so it means he has to know when we scroll down or scroll top, when we resize the window (to change the format at 992px), etc...)

**How can I do it?**

*PS: if you know really good posts where I can find it or examples would be nice.*

*PS2:  I am reading a lot of patron stuff and these things too!*

Thanks to everyone for your time!
Victor.

Comment: I don't think you need JS for this case at all. You can write responsive pages purely in CSS with no need to make complex JS structures. Take a look at *CSS media queries*.

Comment: Where and how you initialize your Menu-component? You should create `init` function where you will create document node which contents your menu, then add `resize` and `scroll` event handlers

Comment: @Al.G. Yes, for the resize I wil use mediaqueries.. but I have to control the scroll anyway, so It is why I wanted to do it in OOP. And encapsulate all the logic in my module

Comment: The way you are starting to do this very much reminds me of the React library. I recommend that you try it, and even if you don't want to use it, you can borrow ideas from the way things are done with it.

Comment: Yes,basically is OOP in "nativeJS", we still cant integrate React but at least, I want to not do spaguetti code anymore. So I can use some patterns.. It is easily to mantain and test aswell" @Al.G.

Comment: I'm still unsure about what you want to do. It seems to me you only need to add `window.addEventListener('scroll', menu.onScroll);` and define `Menu.prototype.onScroll` in terms of the other member functions.

Comment: @Al.G. More os less yes, finally I decided that the best is develop it using the Module Pattern, so, my question is: What if I want to add more listeners? Like some clicks in some buttons inside the menu component? How should I do it?

Comment: Basically, it's the same: `whatever.addEventListener('click', menu.method);`